# How can I change my CommCare worker monitoring reports to another language?

Tags: commcare

My application is in Portuguese and English, with por as the default language. However, my worker monitoring reports reference the English name of all Apps, Modules, and Forms. How do I change this to Portuguese?

Answer (score 5):

You can change your language preferences on your account settings page https://www.commcarehq.org/account/settings/